# Error connecting to MongoDB Cloud from Docker

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, dns

I tested the application on my laptop, my server and another laptop.

I changed the DNS each time but this is the problem I am having:

```
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: None of DNS query names exist: _mongodb._tcp.xxxxxx-shard-00-00-uzn6y.mongodb.net., _mongodb._tcp.xxxxxx-shard-00-00-uzn6y.mongodb.net.
```

The line generating this error is:

```
myclient = MongoClient(con_string)
```

and the con_stirng is:

```
mongodb+srv://root:<password>@xxxxxx-xxxxxx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true
```

I also tried without "srv":

```
mongodb://root:<password>@xxxxxx-xxxxxx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true
```

All of this is running in a Docker container and I am using Flask.
When I run the application without Docker, the DNS is resolved, however, this is not the case when I run it on a container.

These are what I tried until now:

```
docker run -it -p 5000:5000 --env-file vars.env myapp

docker run -it -p 5000:5000  --dns=8.8.8.8 --env-file vars.env myapp

docker network create demo && docker run -it -p 5000:5000  --network demo --env-file vars.env myapp

docker run -it -p 5000:5000  --network demo --volumes /etc/resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf --env-file vars.env myapp

docker run -it -p 5000:5000 --volumes /etc/resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf --env-file vars.env myapp
```

None of the above resolved the mongocloud instance address.

This is the full trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/folder//venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 287, in _get_dns_srv_hosts
    results = resolver.query('_mongodb._tcp.' + hostname, 'SRV')
  File "/folder//venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 1102, in query
    lifetime)
  File "/folder//venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 1002, in query
    raise NXDOMAIN(qnames=qnames_to_try, responses=nxdomain_responses)
dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN: None of DNS query names exist: _mongodb._tcp.xxxxxx-shard-00-00-xxxxxx.mongodb.net., _mongodb._tcp.xxxxxx-shard-00-00-xxxxxx.mongodb.net.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 63, in <module>
    myclient = MongoClient(con_string)
  File "/folder//venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 494, in __init__
    res = uri_parser.parse_uri(entity, port, warn=True)
  File "/folder//venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 399, in parse_uri
    nodes = _get_dns_srv_hosts(fqdn)
  File "/folder//venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 289, in _get_dns_srv_hosts
    raise ConfigurationError(str(exc))
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: None of DNS query names exist: _mongodb._tcp.xxxxxx-shard-00-00-xxxxxx.mongodb.net., _mongodb._tcp.xxxxxx-shard-00-00-xxxxxx.mongodb.net.
```

Comment: `_mongodb._tcp` part doesn't look right. The domain name should start with cluster name. Which version of the driver you are using?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.
The connection host string should be: :

```
xxxxxxxxxx-shard-00-00-xxxxxxxxxxxx.mongodb.net:27017,xxxxxxxx-shard-00-01-xxxxxxxx.mongodb.net:27017,xxxxxxxxx-shard-00-02-xxxxxxxxx.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true
```

Comment: If you're using MongoDB Cloud then: Connect -> Connect your application -> pick python driver **3.4. or later**, you can copy working connection string in this format for your db